# How to perfect grid view on all types of device?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build an app in which 40% of the screen from top is viewflipper and 60% of the screen is a grid of cardview of size 9(9 cardviews).
Each cardview has an imageview and a textview.
I am using recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager for populating the grid.

The problem that i face is, when i run the app on different devices the grid is not consistent, in one device it fits perfectly on the screen but on other device there is empty space left and on another device it goes out of the screen so i have to scroll up and down. I want the 9 cardviews to appear the same on all devices.

[image]

in another device the last row will go off the screen and the margins will also be wrong.
Java file

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CardView cardView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager LayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Grid> list = new ArrayList<Grid>();
    private int[] image_id = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
    private String[] name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);


        percentRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_home_screen);

        name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.persons_name);
        int count = 0;
        for (String Name : name) {
            Grid contact = new Grid(image_id[count], Name);
            count++;
            list.add(contact);
        }


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)
findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_home_screen);
        LayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new GridAdaptar(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

carditem xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/homescreen_card_view"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#eaece5"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/person_image"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:textSize="7dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_image" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

homscreen xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home_screen">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="2000"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img3"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img4"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img5"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </ViewFlipper>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewFlipper_main"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_home_screen"> </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So you always want a 3x3 grid to completely fill 60% of the screen? Meaning that item width/height adapts to the screen size

Comment: Yes,always 3x3,60% of the screen. The cards should adjust so as to fill the 60% of the screen. @MehmetKologlu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because you are giving particular size of imageView in cardItem. So total size of cardItem might exceed the 60% device's size.
As you are using RelativeLayout for cardItem, try using weights instead of specific size (60dp).

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?  Weights with LinearLayout doesn't seem to work.Image height/width when kept wrap_content doesn't work as ultimately it depends on the image size.

Comment: If weights are not working then you can follow following steps: 1. Give wrap_content to height and width. 2. Do not use android:src in xml. 3. Resize your image in java file according to device's size with the help of https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html link. 4. Set resized image to imageview.

Comment: You can also use Constraint Layout. just experiment with it. Please check below links: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html     https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

Comment: Thank you for all your help.But it wont work as ultimately it depends on my image size i.e how big its displayed on different screen resolutions,even though i have used image asset to provide same image for different resolutions its still not perfect,there is always some space left. What you are suggesting is spacing between two cards which wont solve the problem.